# Jest doesn't finish test on done() in callback

Tags: node.js, socket.io, jestjs

I have two asynchronous tests, one of them runs well, and the second one fails to call async callback before timeout. Well, actually I suppose it DOES call the `done()` callback, but everything continues to work.

**First** (correct) is following:

```
    it('User should be verified', done => {
      const wsClient = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:7575/')

      function callback({ user, isNameTaken }) {
        expect(isNameTaken).toBe(false)
        expect(typeof user.id).toBe('string')
        expect(user.name).toBe('Sam')
        done()
      }

      wsClient.emit(VERIFY_USER, 'Sam', callback)
    })
```

**Second** one (incorrect):

```
 it('Do not allow duplicate nicknames', done => {
    const wsClient = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:7575/')
    function callbackFinal({ user, isNameTaken }) {
      console.log('============ CALLBACK B ===============', new Date())
      console.log({ user, isNameTaken })
      console.log({ done })
      try {
        expect(isNameTaken).toBe(true) // 4. Acutal test
        expect(user).toBe(null)
        done()
        console.log('============ CALLBACK B After done() ===============', new Date())
      } catch (e) {
        done(e)
      }          
    }

    function callback({ user, isNameTaken }) {
      console.log('============ CALLBACK A ===============', new Date())
      wsClient.emit(USER_CONNECTED, user) // 2. Add verified user to connected users list
      wsClient.emit(VERIFY_USER, 'Sam', callbackFinal) // 3. Try verifying user for the second time
    }

    wsClient.emit(VERIFY_USER, 'Sam', callback) // 1. Try verifying user for the first time
  })
```

Console output for the second test:

```
FAIL  test/integration/loggingIn.spec.js (7.398s)
● Console

console.log test/integration/loggingIn.spec.js:12
  BEFORE
console.log test/integration/loggingIn.spec.js:79
  ============ CALLBACK A =============== 2018-12-06T12:00:17.500Z
console.log test/integration/loggingIn.spec.js:69
  ============ CALLBACK B =============== 2018-12-06T12:00:17.520Z
console.log test/integration/loggingIn.spec.js:70
  { user: null, isNameTaken: true }
console.log test/integration/loggingIn.spec.js:71
  { done: { [Function: next] fail: [Function] } }
console.log test/integration/loggingIn.spec.js:75
  ============ CALLBACK B After done() =============== 2018-12-06T12:00:17.530Z

● User connection tests › Do not allow duplicate nicknames

Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.
```

Log output shows that callback is fired, and `done()` should be called. I can't get what's wrong with my test, or with jest, or... well, what's wrong here?

**UPD**: here is the repository: https://github.com/dsamoylov/jest-issue

Comment: It's probably because Socket IO does not exit after your test is done. Check this: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#forceexit

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?  I am seeing it while using sockets as well.